# Picture upload field and crop function in edit form

Tags: file-upload, picture-library

I have a standard list and I have to add a special field:

It should be an upload field or a link to a window including an upload field where the user can upload a picture and select an area to crop, so he is uploading maybe a 1000x800 pic and select just a 300x400 area to use.

After selecting the area the cropped picture is then stored into a picture library and that item is linked to item the user is editing in the standard list (via lookup field maybe).

Is there a solution out there for that or do I have to code that by myself? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

jCrop is your answer:

```
public class ImageCrop : LayoutsPageBase
private const string WIDTH = "450";
private const string HEIGHT = "200";
protected Image imgJCrop;
protected Button btnCropImage;
protected Button btnCropImageTop;
string strImageURL;
protected Label lblErr;
protected TextBox txtW;
protected TextBox txtH;
protected Button btnApplyDimensions;

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    this.EnsureChildControls();

    //load jCrop script
    ClientScriptManager sm = Page.ClientScript;
    sm.RegisterHiddenField("jCropX", "0");
    sm.RegisterHiddenField("jCropY", "0");
    sm.RegisterHiddenField("jCropW", WIDTH);
    sm.RegisterHiddenField("jCropH", HEIGHT);

    string strScript = string.Format("<script type='text/javascript'>" +
                                    "var globalX=0;" +
                                    "var globalY=0;" +
                                    "jQuery(document).ready(function() {{" +
                                    "var jcropAPI = $.Jcrop('#{0}',{{onChange: storeCoords}});" +
                                    "jcropAPI.setSelect([0,0,{1},{2}]);" +

                                        "jQuery('#{11}').click(function(e) {{" +
                                        "jcropAPI.setSelect([globalX,globalY,jQuery('#{9}').val(),jQuery('#{10}').val()]); }});" +

                                    "}});" +

                                    "function nothing(e) {{" +
                                    "e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault(); return false;" +
                                    "}};" +

                                    "function storeCoords(c) {{" +
                                    "jQuery('#{3}').val(c.x); " +
                                    "jQuery('#{4}').val(c.y);" +
                                    "jQuery('#{5}').val(c.w);" +
                                    "jQuery('#{6}').val(c.h);" +
                                    "jQuery('#{7}').val(c.w);" +
                                    "jQuery('#{8}').val(c.h);" +
        //"globalX = c.x;" + 
        //"globalY=c.y;" + 
                                    "}};" +
                                    "</script>",
                                    imgJCrop.ClientID,
                                    WIDTH,
                                    HEIGHT,
                                    "jCropX",
                                    "jCropY",
                                    "jCropW",
                                    "jCropH",
                                    txtW.ClientID,
                                    txtH.ClientID,
                                    txtW.ClientID,
                                    txtH.ClientID,
                                    btnApplyDimensions.ClientID);
    this.RegisterStartupScript("jCropJS", strScript);

    //diable server side on button click
    btnApplyDimensions.OnClientClick = "return false;";

    //load image
    //SPSite sitecoll = this.Site;
    if (Request.QueryString["ItemUrl"] != null)
    {
        if (this.Web.ServerRelativeUrl != "/")
            {
                strImageURL = this.Web.Url.TrimEnd('/') + Request.QueryString["ItemUrl"].ToString().Replace(this.Web.ServerRelativeUrl, "");
            }
            else
            {
                strImageURL = this.Web.Url.TrimEnd('/') + Request.QueryString["ItemUrl"].ToString();
            }

            imgJCrop.ImageUrl = strImageURL;
    }

}


protected void btnCropImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(Page.Request["jCropX"]);
    int y = Convert.ToInt32(Page.Request["jCropY"]);
    int w = Convert.ToInt32(Page.Request["jCropW"]);
    int h = Convert.ToInt32(Page.Request["jCropH"]);

    string strListID = Request.QueryString["ListId"];
    //string strWebURL = Request.QueryString["SiteUrl"];
    string strItemID = Request.QueryString["ItemId"];

    lblErr.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Color, "Red");
    lblErr.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.FontSize, "11px");
    lblErr.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.FontWeight, "bold");
    lblErr.Visible = true;

    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
    {
        try
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(this.Site.Url))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(this.Web.ServerRelativeUrl))
                {

                    try
                    {
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                        SPList list = web.Lists[new Guid(strListID)];
                        SPListItem item = list.Items.GetItemById(Convert.ToInt32(strItemID));
                        SPFile file = item.File;

                        if (list.WorkflowAssociations.Count > 0)
                        {
                            //dont crop as it can effect workflow
                            lblErr.Text = "The document library this image belongs to has workflow enabled. Please disable workflows on this document library to enable cropping";

                            btnCropImage.Enabled = false;
                            btnCropImageTop.Enabled = false;
                            return;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lblErr.Visible = false;
                        }

                        if (file.CheckOutStatus != SPFile.SPCheckOutStatus.None)
                        {
                            file.CheckIn("");
                        }

                        file.CheckOut();

                        //use WebRequest to create stream to the document library file
                        WebRequest reqImg = WebRequest.Create(strImageURL);
                        reqImg.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                        WebResponse imgResponse = reqImg.GetResponse();
                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(imgResponse.GetResponseStream());

                        using (System.Drawing.Image imgOriginal = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(reader.BaseStream, true))
                        {
                            using (System.Drawing.Image imgCropped = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(w, h))
                            {
                                using (System.Drawing.Graphics graphic = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(imgCropped))
                                {
                                    graphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                                    graphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                                    graphic.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

                                    System.Drawing.Rectangle rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, w, h);
                                    graphic.DrawImage(imgOriginal, rect, x, y, w, h, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

                                    MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream();
                                    imgCropped.Save(mstream, imgOriginal.RawFormat);

                                    MemoryStream msNew = null;
                                    using (msNew = new MemoryStream(mstream.GetBuffer(), 0, mstream.GetBuffer().Length))
                                    {
                                        msNew.Write(mstream.GetBuffer(), 0, mstream.GetBuffer().Length);
                                        list.RootFolder.Files.Add(file.Name, msNew.ToArray(), true);
                                        file.Item.SystemUpdate(false);
                                        file.CheckIn("");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        lblErr.Visible = true;
                        lblErr.Text = ex.Message;
                        if (web.AllowUnsafeUpdates != false)
                        {
                            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblErr.Visible = true;
            lblErr.Text = ex.Message;
        }

    });
}
```

}

[Visit this page for full description and code.](http://fahadzia.com/blog/2009/08/using-jcrop-for-cropping-document-library-images/)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could use a publishing image field combined with http://spimagefieldupload.codeplex.com